# Do we append consonants when linking words?

Tags: phrases, pronunciation, phonology

How should *in an instant* be spoken?

1. [ɪ nə nɪn.stənt]
2. [ɪn nən nɪn.stənt]

If we use second version, then we append [n] before [ən] and before [n.stənt].

How do I correctly link words together when speaking English naturally?

Comment: When you're speaking English, you ***don't*** pause between words or syllables. (There are consonants like /t/, /k/, /p/ which are pronounced differently when they're syllable-initial and syllable-final, but /n/ isn't one of them.) So how exactly how does /ɪnənɪnstənt/ differ from /ɪnnənnɪnstənt/?

Comment: @PeterShor The IPA itself (I'm not sure about the intention behind it) would indicate the same difference as between (1) _see no_ and (2) _seen no_.

Answer (score 2):

To speak American English most naturally, at least for dialects I'm familiar with, don't link consonants.  Word final consonants before a vowel of a following word will be syllable final if there is no linking, but they will be syllable initial if there is linking.  Generally, syllable final consonants are weakened, while syllable initial consonants are strengthened.  In English, these final consonants are weakened, which tells us that they are syllable final, so we know there has been no linking.  Linking prevents weakening.

There are a number of examples of weakening word final consonants before a vowel beginning a following word.  The most well known and widespread is flapping of t/d/n after a vowel or glide.

Comment: Lots of excellent points. Source?

Comment: @ Greg, so 1 or 2? which one is correct?

Comment: @user105551: What exactly is the difference between 1 and 2? In English, *"a notion"*, and *"an ocean"* are pronounced the same; you can't tell which syllable the /n/ belongs to.

Comment: The example "a notion" and "an ocean" may perhaps be pronounced the same sometimes, but "an ocean" has a pronunciation variant (for dialects which flap) with a nasal flap substituted for "n".  That's because the first "n" of "an ocean" is at the end of a syllable while the first "n" of "a notion" is at the beginning of a syllable.

Comment: user105551, I don't think either 1 or 2 is possible, but 1 is close.  I would say the first two "n"s in 1 as flaps, not "n"s, in normal connected speech.

Comment: Kris, my source is, generally, what I've learned about the phonology of English from my teacher, David Stampe.  The only published papers I can think of which involve syllabic constraints on the flapping of alveolar stops are Stampe's paper "Divinity Fudge", which was in Proceeding of the nth Regional Meeting of the Chicago Linguistic Society, (where n=6,7, or 8), and a subsequent paper in the same series by me and Irwin Howard called "Another Mouthful of Divinity Fudge".

Comment: @Greg: maybe for ***some*** dialects that flap. I use flaps in *"ladder"*, *"better"*, and *"winter"*, but I can't imagine putting a flap in *"an ocean"*.

Comment: Peter, your examples compare flapping d and t within a word with flapping n at the end of a word (before a vowel).  Before deciding for sure, why not consider also flapping n within a word ("banner", "cinnamon") and flapping d and t at the end of a word ("sad ocean", "at any rate")?

Comment: @Greg: I flap 'd' and 't' at the ends of words, and ***never*** flap 'n' unless it's followed by a 't'. (If you flap 'n' within a word, do you distinguish between *winter* and *winner*?)

Comment: No, I don't distinguish *winter* from *winner*.  (But the flap in *winter* is from flapping the t in [wɪ̃tɹ̩̩], which flap is then nasalized.  So, I guess, we could characterize your speech by saying that you just don't flap n.)